# Grab Input Value and Use it in functions.php as an Attribute

Tags: php, wordpress, html

I have a range slider and I want to use the value from that slider in my wordpress functions.php file as an attribute for an already written shortcode function. Basically, it will be a choice of distance from a point. I just need to make the existing distance attribute variable and connected to the range slider which will re-execute the function on submit. I'm very lost on this so any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of different ways to do this really, depending on whether or not you want a page reload when they submit.

**Method 1 - Pass the range value as a url variable**

Submit the value of the form onto the page and then reload it with this data:

```
<form id="distance-form" action="<?php the_permalink() ?>" method="get">
<input type="range" min="0" max="5000" value="0" id="distance">
</form>
```

and then elsewhere on the page you might have the shortcode function which would include the distance value if set.

e.g.

```
function example_shortcode(){

 $distance = intval($_GET['distance']); //Get the url value of distance

 if(!$distance || $distance < 0){ //Or set to zero if not a valid value

   $distance = 0;

 }

  // Then do whatever we need with the function

}
```

**Method 2 - Use AJAX**

We can use a similar method but with AJAX instead, which would need a similar PHP function and a JS function to make the AJAX call.

I'd recommend reading up on AJAX if it's not something you're familiar with, https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/using-ajax-with-wordpress/ is pretty good.

You'd probably end up with something like the following for the js:

```
$("#distance-form").submit(function(event){

event.preventDefault();

jQuery.ajax({
        url : localisedVars.ajax_url,
        type : 'post',
        data : {
            action : 'function_name',
            distance : $("#distance").val()
        },
        success : function( response ) {
            /*Return the shortcode response from our PHP ajax call, we can then put it somewhere on the page*/
        }


})
```

and

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_function_name', 'function_name' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_function_name', 'function_name' );

function function_name() {
     $distance = intval($_POST['distance']); //Get the ajax posted value of distance

 if(!$distance || $distance < 0){ //Or set to zero if not a valid value

   $distance = 0;

 }

  // Then do whatever we need with the function
 echo $response //gets passed to the js function above

die();

}
```

Comment: TY! I'd like to remain on the same page, but atm, whatever works is great. Unfortunately, I'm still very confused. I don't get the action part of the HTML. Plus, the function I am using is within functions.php which doesn't like when I add this. Function: `function calendar_with_latlng_function2( $atts ){
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
  'near_distance' => 25
    ), $atts, 'calendar_with_latlng2' ) );

    $gmw_current_latlng = do_shortcode( '[gmw_current_latlng]' );

    return do_shortcode( '[fullcalendar near='. $gmw_current_latlng .' near_distance='. $near_distance .' ]' );
}`

Comment: and then on my page is the input form and the shortcode. When I hit submit with the action as "URL" I just get the page refreshed with no changes. The slider also goes back to it's original location. Sorry if this is a bit much, you've just been the first to respond. I actually have reworded this question a few times to get an answer, but now I feel as if it's not specific enough.